# Using Twin Macro, TypeScript and jest getting error when resolving

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, styled-components, babel-jest

I get the following error when running my tests

`TypeError: _twinMacro.default.div is not a function`

I'm attempting to use babel-jest to convert it

This is my transform function in jest.config.js

`transform: { "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": [ "babel-jest", { presets: ["next/babel", "@babel/preset-typescript"] }, ], },`

This is my babel-plugin-macros.config.js

`module.exports = { twin: { preset: "styled-components", config: "tailwind.config.js", dataTwProp: true, debugPlugins: false, debug: false, hasSuggestions: true, }, };`

and .babelrc.js file :

`module.exports = { twin: { preset: "styled-components", config: "tailwind.config.js", dataTwProp: true, debugPlugins: false, debug: false, hasSuggestions: true, }, };`